# Excel Hide 0 Values from Bar Chart Axis

Tags: excel, charts

Good morning all,

I have the following data:

[image]

and created the following chart:

[image]

Is it possible to tell excel to hide axis with zero value automatically e.g. like the following chart:

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can display your data in a pivot table you can use a pivot chart. This will allow you to filter for non-zero values only.

- highlight table area including header
- select Insert - Pivot Table (shortcut ALT, N, V)
- (re-)create the desired table
- highlight the pivot table
- select Insert - PivotChart
- left click the filter in the lower left corner of the pivot chart and select Value Filters - Does Not Equal ... - 0